# Backup Solution for Field Netbooks?

Tags: backup, sync, dropbox, online-backup

Windows 7 and Windows 8 Laptops
Connected via cell phone hot spots and twice a week WiFi in the office

We have about 20 computers that are in the field and about once a day at different times they get online to process work. During that time, I'd like them to execute a backup to an online service or back to our server. The amount of data per PC is around 400mb total, with maybe 1mb changing a day. Standard online solutions seem overly expensive for this netbooks.

The computers are not online all of the time so hosting the data only in the cloud will not work, we also looked into terminal services, wont work for us.

I've looked into moving the desktop and documents folders into a dropbox account and setting them up to selective sync. Users will only see their own folder. This works great, with the small exception that new folders added in dropbox automatically are downloaded as it assumes new folders should be sync'd to all clients.

Example Structure:

```
[Dropbox Account]
--User1
---- My Docs
---- Desktop
---- Favorites
--User2
---- My Docs
---- Desktop
---- Favorites
--Shared Folder
---- Subfolder
```

At this point I'm about ready to cave in and say there is no way to do it without paying for an online service per computer. At that point they will say it is not in the budget and nothing will be done.

Anyone else have a creative idea on how to solve this problem? I would also like to make my life easier by not have a free account per computer, so that it can be managed from a central location.

Comment: Business versions of Dropbox and Carbonite might suite your needs

Comment: What makes Dropbox look better is the data is live and we would like to push "updates" new forms and word docs out to all users. Offline sync of a network drive is really what I think we need.

Answer (score 1):

> **DSynchronize** is a stand-alone utility that let you periodically synchronize two or more folders on Hard Disk, Floppy Disk, LAN, USB
>   Key, CD-DVD (with packet writing software) and FTP server.
>
> It is also possible to specify the time and the day to schedule the
>   synchronization to run, and to create some additional "filters" for
>   other factors.
>
> Real-Time sync is also supported.

Visit [Dimio's Tools](http://dimio.altervista.org/eng/), download [Dsynchronize](http://dimiodati.altervista.org/dsynchronize.zip). It has a lot of options you can try out. You can back up your data at a specific time each day, specific days of month or days of week. It also supports backing up data after every specified time interval.

Also it supports incremental backups. It can stamp your backed up data with date information to let you know when a particular backup was made.

You can run the program as a service in Windows services for automating the process of backing up.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [CrashPlan](http://www.code42.com/crashplan/).  The free version will allow you to back up to an off site computer.